# how to create such Javascript that would provide different swfs depending on users flash player version

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, flash

So I have swf9.swf swf10.0.swf and swf10.1 for fp 9.0, 10, 10.1. How to write such JS that would push difrent swfs to user? (I would like to keep using my default flex builder html swfobject.js script if possible - so question is how to using it create code in main html file. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion()` to get the flash version.  Then just use an `if` statement to check for which version to use.

I haven't tested this, but something similar should work

```
var version = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion();
if (version.major == 9)
{
    //load swf for flash 9
}
else if (version.major == 10 && version.minor == 0)
{
    //load swf for flash 10
}
else if (version.major == 10 && version.minor == 1)
{
    //load swf for flash 10.1
}
```

See http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api for a reference of what `swfobject` can do.